# dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance - Monotouch

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin

When I call this line:

```cs
((UIImagePickerController)sender).DismissViewController (true, () => {});
```

I get this error. Please help

```
MonoTouch.Foundation.MonoTouchException: Objective-C exception thrown.  Name: NSInvalidArgumentException Reason: -[UIImagePickerController dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xb647ed0
    at (wrapper managed-to-native) MonoTouch.ObjCRuntime.Messaging:void_objc_msgSend_bool_IntPtr (intptr,intptr,bool,intptr)
    at MonoTouch.UIKit.UIViewController.DismissViewController (Boolean animated, MonoTouch.Foundation.NSAction completionHandler) [0x00036] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/monotouch/src/UIKit/UIViewController.g.cs:678
    at ECPIInstructorObservationForm.Section1.Handle_FinishedPickingMedia (System.Object sender, MonoTouch.UIKit.UIImagePickerMediaPickedEventArgs e) [0x00142] in /Users/kjohnson/Projects/ECPIInstructorObservationForm/ECPIInstructorObservationForm/Section1.cs:298
    at MonoTouch.UIKit.UIImagePickerController+_UIImagePickerControllerDelegate.FinishedPickingMedia (MonoTouch.UIKit.UIImagePickerController picker, MonoTouch.Foundation.NSDictionary info) [0x00014] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/monotouch/src/UIKit/UIImagePickerController.g.cs:601
    at (wrapper managed-to-native) MonoTouch.UIKit.UIApplication:UIApplicationMain (int,string[],intptr,intptr)
    at MonoTouch.UIKit.UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, System.String principalClassName, System.String delegateClassName) [0x0004c] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/monotouch/src/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:38
    at ECPIInstructorObservationForm.Application.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in /Users/kjohnson/Projects/ECPIInstructorObservationForm/ECPIInstructorObservationForm/Main.cs:17
```

Answer (score 1):

The `dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:` selector was introduced in iOS 5.0 - are you running on an earlier iOS version?

**Update**

I just tried running this code:

```
var picker = new UIImagePickerController ();
picker.DismissViewController (true, () => Console.WriteLine ("foo!"));
```

and it ran just fine on my machine, which means the code you've shown is not enough to reproduce the issue you're seeing - so maybe you can show how you're creating and using the image picker?

Answer (score 0):

Using DismissViewController completion handler is the way to go

```
picker.DismissViewController (true,() => {
    var labelPicsViewController = new LabelPicsViewController();
    PresentViewController(labelPicsViewController,true,null);
});
```